# Migrating from Google Maps JavaScript API V2 to V3, encoded polygons?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The application I'm migrating takes heavy advantage of encoded polygons, for example, for one polygon, the coordinates are in the format:

Encoded coords:
ih}rJ|ixk^lLuJhM_i@fG?zGnKlG?|E_G|FwSaDf]yGhhBaBv}BcDvBwNwHsM~D}EWuJaH{Nf_@{Da^sTofAF_LjDePtH}KFmZ`E?fQad@jEsC

Level code:
PEGEDGDICEHEEDEGJDDHDEFEDP

However, I've searched the net and can't seem to find a definitive answer if V3 accepts these encoded polygons? These are the only coordinates I have... I don't have the lat/lng coordinates, so am I screwed? Can the application be migrated to V3?

Answer (score 1):

The v3 API supports decoding the encoded coordinates.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#encoding

Paste your encoded polygon string into here:

[http://www.geocodezip.com/blitz-gmap-editor/test5.html](http://www.geocodezip.com/blitz-gmap-editor/test5.html?encoded=ih%7DrJ%7Cixk%5ElLuJhM_i%40fG%3FzGnKlG%3F%7CE_G%7CFwSaDf%5DyGhhBaBv%7DBcDvBwNwHsM~D%7DEWuJaH%7BNf_%40%7BDa%5EsTofAF_LjDePtH%7DKFmZ%60E%3FfQad%40jEsC)

click "generate polygon from encoded"

[discussion on the google maps api v2 group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-maps-api/f2KC9SfEDYI/mwyk4Alm_i0J)